# Nested map to list of string

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, java-stream

I have a map with this structure

```
Map<String, Object> data

    "data": {
       "contacts": [
        "20228",
        "20118"
        ],
  "phone": "555555"
}
```

I would like to know how can I get a list from this data map, something like:

```
List<String> expectedOutput = ["20228", "20118", "555555"]
```

I tried with this

```
var list = data.values().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But I am getting a List with the nested list of contacts and this not what I am expecting to have.

Comment: Where does `368188` come from? And why do you have a map like that?  They are cumbersome to uae.

Comment: Mistake, check the edit

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("a", List.of("a1", "a2"));
map.put("b", "b1");

List<String> list =
    (List<String>)
        map
            .values()                        // Collection<Object>
            .stream()                        // Stream<Object>
            .flatMap(
                o -> {
                  if (o instanceof List) {
                    return ((List) o).stream();
                  } else {
                    return Stream.of(o);
                  }
                })                           // Stream<Object>
            .collect(Collectors.toList());   // Object

System.out.println(list);                    // [a1, a2, b1]
```

You have a weird situation here. You have a `Stream` of objects which can have `Stream`s or `primitive` types -- which is not a good design, imo.

The goal can still be achieved with `.flatMap()`. You'll need to cast the `.collect()` because the `Stream` interface relies on generic typing, and you erased all it's benefits by starting a `Stream<Object>` so the return type of your stream pipeline is `Object` when its source is a raw type.

---

One liner for `.flatMap()`:

```
.flatMap(o -> o instanceof List ? ((List) o).stream() : Stream.of(o))
```